Is there an Opensearch counterpart to Grafana alert pending logic?
I`m currently migrating alerts from Grafana to Opensearch v 2.6.0.
Is there an OS counterpart to Grafana alert pending logic?

When the condition is first breached, the rule goes into a “pending”
state.
The rule stays in the “pending” state until the condition has been
broken for the required amount of time - pending period.
Once the required time has passed, the rule goes into a “firing”
state.
If the condition is no longer broken during the pending period, the
rule goes back to its normal state.



It`s possible to create similar logic using several monitors(firing and OK) combined in a composite monitor(alert) responsible for user alerting based on delegate monitors triggers. Composite monitors are available in Opensearch starting at v2.9.0.
